# iphone programming objective-c : mkannotation Pin problem

Tags: iphone, dictionary, gps, mkannotation

i tryed to make a customized pin on the map with green color and with a button.
but it doesnt work. I have a class named Placemark that implement mkannotation protocol.
This is my method that supposed to show a green pin but it doesnt:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *) map:(MKMapView *)map viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation{
    MKPinAnnotationView *annView=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"currentloc"];
    annView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
    annView.animatesDrop=TRUE;
    annView.canShowCallout = YES;
    annView.calloutOffset = CGPointMake(-5, 5);
    return annView;
}
```

i also want to specified that my MKMapview is called "map" and its an IBOutlet.

thanks

Comment: Can you post the code where you are adding the annotations to the map view with `addAnnotations:`?

Answer (score 1):

The method name must be `mapView:viewForAnnotation:`.  The map view looks specifically for that name.  You can change the internal parameter variable names but not the parts before the colons.

Try this:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)map 
                            viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation
```

With that misspelling, the map view doesn't call your viewForAnnotation method and must be putting a default red pin on the map.

Comment: well i did that but it doesnt enter method more

Comment: You mean it still doesn't call the method?  Make sure the map view's delegate is connected in IB.

Comment: Besides using the correct method name and making sure the delegate is set, next thing to check would be whether the annotation is actually getting added to the map view's annotations array.  After the addAnnotation line, NSLog the count of the annotations array (or just log the whole array).  Do you see the annotation being added to the array?  Otherwise, post the code that creates the placemark and calls addAnnotation.  I'll look at it when I'm online again or someone else may also be able to help before then.